# Create batch file with multiple named parameters

Tags: batch-file, optional-parameters, named-parameters

I got a requirement to create batch file with multiple optional parameters.

**Example**

```
MyTestSqlBatch.bat ServerName DatabaseName [UserId] [Password] [Command] [parameter]
```

here `ServerName` and `DatabaseName` are **mandatory**. And 
`UserId, Password`  are optional for Windows authentication users.
`Command` is also optional parameter (some times I need to call batch file with `Command` parameter for Windows authentication). if I want to run my batch file for SQL authentication then I want to pass **UserId password** also.

Can any one give suggest on this, how to create named parameters (or) any best way to handle this?

Thanks,

Comment: `%1` `%2` etc..

Comment: To pass empty parameters, do `MyTestSqlBatch.bat ServerName DatabaseName "" "" "Command"`; in the script use `%~1` to remove the quotes...

Comment: You could also use prefixes for parameters to avoid specify empty strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create batch file with named and optional parameters.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set SVR=%1
set DB=%2


set uid=
set pwd=
set CM=
set CP=

:loop
IF NOT "%1"=="" (
    IF "%1"=="-SVR" (
        SET SVR=%2
        SHIFT
    )
    IF "%1"=="-DB" (
        SET DB=%2
        SHIFT
    )

    IF "%1"=="-UserId" (
        SET uid=%2
        SHIFT
    )
    IF "%1"=="-Password" (
        SET pwd=%2
        SHIFT
    ) 
    IF "%1"=="-Command" (
        SET CM=%2
        SHIFT
    )
    IF "%1"=="-Parameter" (
        SET CP=%2
        SHIFT
    )
    SHIFT
    GOTO :loop
)

echo Server       : %SVR%
echo Database     : %DB%

echo Command      : %CM% %CP%

echo UserId : %uid%
echo Password : %pwd%
```

**Syntax:**

```
MyTestSqlBatch.bat -SVR [ServerName] -DB [Database] -Command [value] -Parameter [value] -UserId [value] -Password [value]
```

**Example:**

```
MyTestSqlBatch.bat -SVR local -DB SampleDB -UserId sa -Password Test1234
```

Answer (score 3):

Simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "params=%*"
set "%params: =" & set "%"

echo Server       : %SVR%
echo Database     : %DB%
echo Command      : %Command% %Parameter%
echo UserId       : %UserId%
echo Password     : %Password%
```

**Syntax:**

```
MySqlBatch.bat [SVR=ServerName] [DB=Database] [Command=value] [Parameter=value] [UserId=value] [Password=value]
```

**Example:**

```
MySqlBatch.bat SVR=local DB=SampleDB UserId=sa Password=Test1234
```

Further details at [Split string with string as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600775/split-string-with-string-as-delimiter/33131797#33131797). Pay attention to the *comment* at such an answer...