# How to filter a string in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to handle the string such as `project_Name_-_sofeware_Name.txt` into `project_Name.txt`, so I wrote a script like following to run:

```
set temp1=%~n1
echo %temp1:-*=%
```

But the output of the bat still been `project_Name_-_sofeware_Name.txt`.

I have also written another bat file to get the folder name:

```
:GetFolderName
set temp2=%temp1%
set temp1=%temp2:*\=% 
If Not %temp1%==%temp2% Goto GetFolderName
```

And the output string is in line with expectations by far.

It also is weird. In my opinion, it should be FolderName after running `temp1=%temp2:*\=%`.

Comment: This is interesting. Where do you get the `%temp1:-*=%` construct from? Well, it does _not_ work in Batch files... **`:/`**

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Are you suggesting to use a 1000-lines Batch-JScript hybrid script or an entirely different language to perform something that can be achieved in a very simple and short Batch line? I don't think it is a good advice... **`:(`**

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=$" %%a in ("%temp1:_-_=$%") do echo %%a`

Comment: @Aacini, misread the question, thought it was about replacing `=` :)

Comment: I'd never use string manipulation to get components of a path; rather I'd use the [`~` modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variables...

Answer (score 2):

You may do that in a very simple way:

```
@echo off

set "temp1=project_Name_-_sofeware_Name.txt"

set "dummy=%temp1:_-_=" & set "temp2=%"

echo %temp2%
```

Further details at [Split string with string as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600775/split-string-with-string-as-delimiter/33131797#33131797). Pay attention to the *comment* at such an answer...